# If T maps R-n ONTO R-m, is the nullity of $T = n-m$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm trying to find the dimension of the kernel of T when T: R-n onto R-m, which is the same as its nullity. I know the nullity of a matrix is equal to the number of free variable, and the standard matrix A of a transformation has columns that span R-m if T is onto. So if A has m pivot positions, then would it be correct to say A has $n-m$ free variables, which is the same as it's nullity and the dimension of the kernel of T?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the rank nullity theorem, the dimension of the domain of a linear map is equal to the sum of the dimension of its image plus its nullity.

As $T$ is supposed to be onto, the dimension of the image of $T$ is equal to $m$ and indeed the nullity is equal to $n-m$.